# Is there a way to get icloud photos into nodejs web application, through mobile connection via USB?

Tags: ios, node.js, iphone, icloud

We stuck into a situation where we have to read icloud photos (using a nodejs web application) once a phone connected into windows pc using USB cable.

When we are saying icloud photos, it means the photo which are available on icloud storage but not on phone's internal storage.

Please help us to get the way, if any solution is available.

How to force iphone to download all the icloud images, when connected to USB, using nodejs???

What we achieved till date - using nodejs NodeRT library, we are able to access Phone's internal storage.
That means whatever icloud photos are available inside the internal storage, we can read them.